# Parsing routine not working on Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, httpresponse

I coded this parsing routine some time ago for a java console program and it works fine. Today I tried to put it into an android project but it seems not to work properly.

```
public static String[] parser(String pageOut,String delim1,int offset1,String delim2,int offset2,int relieve)
{
    if(pageOut.length()<delim1.length()){
        String[] mid={"",pageOut};
        return mid;
    }

    String[] results=new String[2];
    int index=pageOut.indexOf(delim1)+delim1.length()+offset1;
    if(index==-1 | index==0){
        String[] mid={"",pageOut};
        return mid;
    }
    String left=pageOut.substring(index,pageOut.length());
    int index2=left.indexOf(delim2)+offset2;
    results[0]=left.substring(0,index2);
    results[1]="";
    if(relieve==1)
        results[1]=left.substring(index2+delim2.length(),left.length());
    return results;
}
```

May it not work because I got the input string(pageOut in the routine) from an httpRequest? However I got it back this way and it seems to be the right string if displayed on the screen.

```
        HttpResponse responseReq;
        responseReq = client.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity=responseReq.getEntity();
        response=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Someone has any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems not to work properly"? Show the input, the desired output and the actual (incorrect) output.

Comment: It gives back the whole pageOut string as first(number #0) item of the results array where there should be anything(in case it goes out from the first if) or the string between the two delimiter(delim1 and delim2). The weird thing is that if I use the same function in a java console program with the same input it work perfectly

Comment: You run the method with arguments X and Y and you expect it to return W, but it returns Z instead. What are X, Y, W and Z?

Comment: I tun the method with X, Y, Z and I espect it to return W, but it returns X(pageOut string). So X is a page from this website(http://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-italiano.php): I'm testing it with the word "mens". Y and Z(delimiters) are "<span class=\"lemma\">" and "</span>".  I expect the method to give back "mens"

Comment: It was my fault!! I'd written bad a variable name and this causes an unexpected response. thanks for help and sorry for the stupid mistake